# Why pass the program name as a parameter to main?

Tags: c, arguments

If I call:

```
./program hello world
```

then:

```
argc would be 3.
argv[0] would be "./program".
argv[1] would be "hello".
argv[2] would be "world".
```

What's the purpose of passing "./program" as an argument? In fact, it's not an argument at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One use is so that the application can know how it was invoked (essentially, what its own name is).

Note that what appears in `argv[]` is implementation-defined.  If you use one of the UNIX [`exec()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) functions, for instance, the contents can be whatever you like.

Answer (score 4):

You can make symbolic links to the same binary. Depending on what link you use, you will get different behaviour. Busybox is an example of this.

Answer (score 2):

...and you can make make a nice help-function that display a help-text when invoked that doesn't need to be updated when the name of the executable changes.